# Which port is used for running schtasks.exe in a remote computer?

Tags: windows, powershell, schtasks

I was trying to extract the list of scheduled tasks in a number of remote computers, and found this `schtasks.exe`. I put this inside a powershell script and run against a list of servers, and almost 80% of the servers returned the results. This was the command I used.

```
$Output = & schtasks.exe /query /v /s $Server /fo csv 2>&1
```

I am wondering which port it used to connect to the remote computer and extracted the data, because this is a very controlled environment with non standard ports are not open. I also need to find out why the 20% of servers failed, perhaps some port is not open there ? I understand from [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/christwe/2012/06/20/what-port-does-powershell-remoting-use/) that powershell remote uses TCP/5985 = HTTP and TCP/5986 = HTTPS, but from what i checked, these ports are not open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `procmon` from `sysinternals` shows that `schtasks` uses the `epmap` port.

`epmap`is port 135 *(Endpoint  Mapper)*. After that, the conversation seems to continue on a newly created connection at port `49154`. Repeating the excercise always uses port `49154` so I assume that `schtasks` needs port `135` and `49154` to be able to get a response from a remote server.

**Edit** <sub>cudo's to Barry</sub>

schtasks.exe definitely connects via port 135, then uses a dynamic port ranging from 49152 to 65535, source docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/…. What I've observed is that it will consistently use one port for a while, and then for reasons that I haven't discovered it will start using another port

[image]

Comment: Thanks man. I found that these 2 ports are open for AD related stuffs. So yea, that works. Thank you

Comment: For anyone else that comes across this, schtasks.exe definitely connects via port 135, then uses a dynamic port ranging from 49152 to 65535, source https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/default-dynamic-port-range-tcpip-chang.  What I've observed is that it will consistently use one port for a while, and then for reasons that I haven't discovered it will start using another port.